# Drools Regex to Match Non-Alpha

Tags: java, drools, business-rules

According to the [Drools Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.M2/drools-expert-docs/html/ch05.html), I should be able to match the following regex in a rule, since the matches operator

> "Matches a field against any valid Java Regular Expression."

However,

```
$firstName : String(value matches "[^A-Za-z]") from $person.name.firstName
```

results in an error when attempting to evaluate the rule.  What am I missing here?

*Edit* - originally had "contains" instead of "matches" in the expression.  This was a type-o made when re-typing an expression similar to the one I'm working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link contains the text **The Operator matches** Matches a field against any valid Java Regular Expression.

```
$firstName : String(this matches ".*[^A-Za-z].*") from $person.name.firstName
```

Note that the word is "matches" and not "find"!

**Edit**

And you cannot use "value" with String, there's no such method.

Comment: As JAndy has correctly pointed out, it may be simpler to use this with a "Person" pattern.

Comment: This regex fixed it, and I did have to change the object like Andy suggested - since String doesn't have a "value" field the above is not correct.  Didn't pick up on that distinction between matches and find, I just assumed that matches did the same thing as something like String's .find method.

Comment: The `value` escaped me. But you can use - see modified answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `matches` operator and you should probably write your drl like

```
when:
  Person( firstName matches "[^A-Za-z]" )
then:
  // ..
end
```

The doc for `contains` says

> The operator contains is used to check whether a field that is a Collection or array contains the specified value.

So it cannot be used for a String

Comment: This is not correct: the operator runs a "matches", not a "find".

Comment: Yeah, so it was a combination of pulling the wrong object and a bad regex.  Just didn't comb over this one well enough.